# bzr could not complete pull, now files are missing

Tags: bazaar

I `bzr pull`ed from a repo. Some of the new files (related to a *TeX* documentation) in the repo apparently could not be placed in the corresponding local dir since there was some kind of lock. I had TeXStudio open, I am not sure if it locked a directory.
The `pull` operation reported an error (which I missed since the shell window was later closed).

Now the status of my local dirs is:

1. `bzr pull` shows the system is up to date.

```
$ bzr pull
Using saved parent location: XXXXX
No revisions or tags to pull.
```

2. The local dir is empty. There should be some files (I actually have them in the local dir in another computer).

I guess `.bzr` contains the required info.
**Is there any way to fix the local copy?**

Comment: Does `bzr status` report any deleted files in the working directory? Perhaps `bzr check` or `bzr revert` works. Or just delete the local repository and branch/pull again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run:

```
bzr co
```

(without any arguments)

To create a working tree for the current branch.